# SQL Server Performance in ADO.NET vs SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

Before I begin, I've read several posts here regarding past performance issue's people have had executing SQL statements/procedures in ADO vs in SSMS.  I've spent the better part of the day trying to solve this issue on my own...reindexing, using `sp_recompile`, adding `Option(Recompile)` to my procedure.  Nothing has worked, so I'm turning to the community for assistance.

I have a stored procedure that one of my web applications executes for running reports.  This procedure in particular is made up of mostly dynamic SQL to allow different report results to come back...sort of a dynamic reporting feature on my site.  Anyhow, some reports can be run (using the same procedure) and results come back almost immediately.  However, other options can be used and the procedure might take several minutes to run.  However, manually running the procedure with those same options in SSMS gives immediate results.  It sounds like some type of plan caching issue, but after recompiling the procedure and adding `WITH(RECOMPILE)`, it's still running dreadfully slow in ADO.NET.

So I started looking at SQL profiles, perhaps one of the "SET" commands ADO is using is causing the issue.  However, after using the same exact SET commands it's still returns almost immediately using SSMS.

I tried using `DBCC freeproccache` and, `DBCC freesystemcache` to clear out any stored plan, however this didn't help as well.

One other thing I tried was taking the dynamic SQL that gets generated in the procedure and running it directly in the SqlCommand statement.  There are no parameters here, just plain SQL.  Again it runs immediately in SSMS but takes forever in ADO.NET.

Is there a way (running ADO.NET) to see the plan that gets generated?  I can do this in SSMS, however that won't help me here since it runs fine in SSMS.

If it's of any help, here is the raw SQL statement...

```
SELECT sf.ID [FileID], sb.ID [BillID], sb.Client_BillID, sf.BobID [ClientID], c.Name [ClientName], c.Parent_ID [ParentID], pnt.Name [ParentName], Network_ID, Facility_Name, OON, sb.TaxID, Inpatient, sf.ProcessDate, sb.Reversed, sb.State, sb.Product, sb.FormType, n.Direct 
INTO #t1 FROM SubmitterFiles sf WITH(NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN SubmitterBills sb WITH (NOLOCK) ON sf.ID = sb.FileID 
LEFT JOIN PPORecords r WITH (NOLOCK) ON sb.RecordID = r.ID 
LEFT JOIN PPONetworks n WITH (NOLOCK) ON r.Network_ID = n.ID 
LEFT JOIN PPOProviders p WITH (NOLOCK) ON r.Provider_ID = p.ID 
INNER JOIN Clients c WITH (NOLOCK) ON sf.BobID = c.ID 
LEFT JOIN Clients pnt WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.Parent_ID = pnt.ID 
WHERE sf.ProcessDate BETWEEN 'Dec  1 2012 12:00AM' and 'Dec 31 2012 12:00AM' 
AND ISNULL(sb.Status,'') NOT IN ('E','V') 
AND (c.Parent_ID IN (1989) or c.ID  IN (1989)) 
; 

SELECT TOP 100 0 as [placeholder],NULL AS BillID, NULL AS Client_BillID, NULL AS DOS
,NULL AS Network_ID
,NULL AS Client_ID
,NULL AS Client_Name
,NULL As ProcessDate
,NULL As ProcessMonth
,NULL AS SubClientID
,NULL AS SubClientName
,Product
,TaxID
, FacilityName
, LastName
, FirstName
,State
,County
,NULL As ProcCode
,NULL As FormType
,NULL As Inpatient, NULL AS Outpatient
,COUNT(DISTINCT sb.BillID) AS [Total_Bills]
,SUM(sl.Amount) AS  [Total_Charges]
,SUM(sl.StateSavings) AS [Total_StateSavings]
,SUM(sl.PPOSavings) AS [Total_PPOSavings]
,COUNT(DISTINCT TaxID) AS [Total_Unique_TaxIds]
,0,0,0,0,0
,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sb.OON = 1 THEN sb.BillID ELSE NULL END) AS [Out_Bills]
,SUM(CASE WHEN sb.OON = 1 THEN sl.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [Out_Charges]
,SUM(CASE WHEN sb.OON = 1 THEN sl.StateSavings ELSE 0 END) AS [Out_StateSavings]
,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sb.OON = 1 THEN sb.TaxID ELSE NULL END) AS [Out_Unique_TaxIds]
,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0
 FROM SubmitterLines sl  WITH (NOLOCK, INDEX(IX_SubmitterLines_BillID))
 INNER JOIN #t1 sb WITH(NOLOCK) ON sl.BillID = sb.BillID
 INNER JOIN SubmitterBillProviders sbp WITH(NOLOCK) ON sb.BillID = sbp.ID
 INNER JOIN SubmitterBillZipCounty sbc WITH(NOLOCK) ON sb.BillID = sbc.ID
 WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY Product
,TaxID
,FacilityName, LastName, FirstName
,State
,County
ORDER BY [Out_Bills] DESC
```

Comment: In title `ADO` in tags `ADO.NET`. Correct please.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest ditching the dynamic SQL in your sproc, otherwise the execution plan will always be suboptimal to the task. Similar to how SQL can't plan well in executing scalar functions, the dynamic SQL will always be a surprise and the system will have difficulty optimizing its execution.

Comment: Darth - Dynamic SQL has it's place.  I know it's not going to be optimal, however it doesn't seem to be the cause of the current issue.  Extracting the SQL and executing still reproduces the issue.

Comment: Have you tried adding the query hint `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` ?

Comment: @YS. - I just tried this but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @DarthContinent:  This is incorrect.  The potential performance problems with dynamic sql have nothing to do with a sub-optimal execution plan, they have to do with having to generate the execution plan at all.  Dynamic SQL is more likely than parametized sql to have to generate a unique query plan.  That small extra work is why Dynamic SQL can be slower.  However, there are common cases (and reports tend to be one of them) where it is more efficient to generate a unique plan every time than it is to reuse one common plan that is inefficient for all parameter values.

Comment: Are you really using the TOP 100 in both your SSMS and ADO.net tests?

Comment: Never mind, just saw your answer...

Comment: @RBarryYoung - The TOP 100 is actually an option in the SP that builds that query.  It's there to limit the result set to target only the top X values.  So that particular part was consistent in both the ADO.net and SSMS tests.  However the query above that that selects into the temp table was being limited to only 1000 rows from the SSMS environment.  I'm still unsure why this didn't show up in the SET's when I ran a trace...

Comment: The ROWCOUNT limit is a (pretty old) legacy setting that has been deprecated for some time.  A lot of that really old stuff can fall under the "notification" radar.

Answer (score 1):

This was one of those problems that kept me up last night so I started going over everything again.  It finally struck me that in SSMS, I have my default row count set to 1000.  What kind of bugs me though is when I ran a trace in SQL Profiler, this didn't show up with the other SET's.  Setting the ROWCOUNT back to 0 allowed me to reproduce this in SSMS allowing me to see the execution plan and fix the issue causing the query to run slow.

At the end of the day, it wasn't an ADO issue - it was a setting that I put in SSMS to limit the number of rows I normally like to return.  Since part of my query builds a temp table of a  larger result set, that temp table was only being populated with 1000 rows.

Comment: Related note for future readers from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx: apparently Microsoft is making some changes regarding this in future releases of SQL Server: "Using SET ROWCOUNT will not affect DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in the next release of SQL Server. Avoid using SET ROWCOUNT with DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it."

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this SO thread? [SQL Server query runs slower from ADO.NET than in SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750369/sql-server-query-runs-slower-from-ado-net-than-in-ssms)

Could the Showplan XML Event Class, as suggested in the accepted answer, work?